# Recycler Adapter Not updating with updated adapter

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a **fragment_1** which has button call **ADD** which send user to **fragment_2**
to fill form with 4 5 **Edit Text** and on same fragment_2 user need to press **Save Form** to return back to fragment_1 with details filled on fragment_2 till here everything is working fine.In log i can see **fragment_1 getting data from fragment_2**

**Fragment_1** which has `RecyclerView` to show user form filled on **Fragment_2**

My **problem** is as i am getting data in **fragment_1** in separate method.In that method i am calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
which supposed to call adapter methods but only `getItemCount` is running not other method which process `RecyclerView`.
Please Check **Logcat** below to get Idea about issue

Here is my method where i am calling `notifydatasetchanged()`

```
   public void PPL_Location(PPL_list_wrapper ppl_list_wrapper){
        PPL_wrapper=ppl_list_wrapper;
        Log.d(TAG,"PROFILE DATA CALLING");
        Log.d(TAG,ppl_list_wrapper.toString());
        Loc_details.add(PPL_wrapper);
        Log.d(TAG,PPL_wrapper.getName());
        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),Loc_details);
        int item=adapter.getItemCount();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d(TAG,"Here is the value of Location Details: "+"Size "+Loc_details.size()+" "+"Details "+Loc_details.iterator()+" "+ "Location "+Loc_details.get(0)+" "+item);
    }
```

Here is my Adapter called **PPL_Re_Adapter**

```
public class ppl_Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ppl_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<PPL_list_wrapper> ppl_Details;
    Context context;
    public static final String TAG="PPL_Re_Adapter####";


    public ppl_Recycler_Adapter(Context context,List<PPL_list_wrapper> ppl_Details ) {
        this.ppl_Details=ppl_Details;
        this.context=context;
        Log.d(TAG,"Adapter Constructor Running With Parameters");

    }


    @Override
    public ppl_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ppl_single_row,parent,false);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate View Holder");    
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ppl_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder");
        if (ppl_Details.size()==0){
            Log.d(TAG,"List is Null");    
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Process Views Here");
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (ppl_Details==null && ppl_Details.isEmpty()){
            Log.d(TAG,"List Is Null");    
            return 0;    
        }
       else {
            Log.d(TAG,"List Is Not Null");
            Log.d(TAG,"Array Size is "+ppl_Details.size());
            return ppl_Details.size();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView ppl_Image;
        TextView ppl_name;
        TextView ppl_address;
        TextView ppl_timePeriod;
        ImageButton ppl_delete;
        ImageButton ppl_Verify;
        FloatingActionButton fab;    

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG,"View Holder Running");
            ppl_Image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.past_permanent_location_picture);
            ppl_name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            ppl_address= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            ppl_timePeriod= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_period);
            ppl_delete= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            ppl_Verify= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.verify);
            fab= (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PPL_fab_Add_PPL);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);    
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context=v.getContext();
            Intent showPPL_Form=new Intent(context,Add_PPL.class);
            context.startActivity(showPPL_Form);
        }
    }
```

**Here Is Logcat**.In Logcat none of the Log showing in logcat from adapter then `getItemCount`

```
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/====Fragment_1====: PROFILE DATA CALLING
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/====Fragment_1====: com.example.com.pro_working1.mainActivityFragments.PPL_list_wrapper@426c3f50
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/====Fragment_1====: n sana
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Adapter Constructor Running With Parameters
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: List Is Not Null
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Array Size is 1
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/====Fragment_1====: Here is the value of Location Details: Size 1 Details java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator@426c51d8 Location com.example.com.pro_working1.mainActivityFragments.PPL_list_wrapper@426c3f50 1
09-06 16:12:46.513 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/Navigation Drawer*****: Here is PPL DATA com.example.com.pro_working1.mainActivityFragments.PPL_list_wrapper@426c3f50
09-06 16:12:46.523 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Adapter Constructor Running With Parameters
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: List Is Not Null
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Array Size is 0
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: List Is Not Null
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Array Size is 0
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: List Is Not Null
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Array Size is 0
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: List Is Not Null
09-06 16:12:46.533 28727-28727/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/PPL_Re_Adapter####: Array Size is 0
```

Fragment_1 Complete Code

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    List<PPL_list_wrapper> Loc_details=new ArrayList<PPL_list_wrapper>();
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    PPL_list_wrapper PPL_wrapper;
    public static final String TAG="====Fragment_1====";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);
        mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),Loc_details);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        fab= (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.PPL_fab_Add_PPL);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Add_PPL add_ppl=new Add_PPL();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,add_ppl);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });




        return view;

    }

    public void PPL_Location(PPL_list_wrapper ppl_list_wrapper){
        PPL_wrapper=ppl_list_wrapper;
        Log.d(TAG,"PROFILE DATA CALLING");
        Log.d(TAG,ppl_list_wrapper.toString());
        Loc_details.add(PPL_wrapper);
        Log.d(TAG,PPL_wrapper.getName());
        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),Loc_details);
        int item=adapter.getItemCount();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Loc_details.add(PPL_wrapper);
        Log.d(TAG,"Here is the value of Location Details: "+"Size "+Loc_details.size()+" "+"RecyclerView "+mRecyclerView+" "+ "Location "+Loc_details.get(0)+" "+"Item Size "+item);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.invalidate();


    }
```

Comment: add listview.setAdapter(adapter) again after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @user2564055 this not going to work.I tried

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and it worked for me:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(newList));
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

In your case its not happened because you are giving new data to your previous activity so first you have to fill your container and then need to send adapter again and invalidate.

Comment: when i call mRecyclerView in my fragment method it always return null even after `findviewbyid` , `setlayoutmanager` . So i can't call recyclerview in my method

Comment: Paste whole code so can understand the problem. @Ritu

Comment: `D/====Fragment_1====: Here is the value of Location Details: Size 2 RecyclerView null Location com.example.com.pro_working1.mainActivityFragments.PPL_list_wrapper@4257c1d8 Item Size 1` Check Details after implement your code See Null Value of RecyclerView

Comment: can you please send me your whole code in my email so let me check? @Ritu

Comment: i added complete fragment_1 code above please check

Comment: check your data set , its empty, problem is there. your dataset can not adding your data properly. @Ritu

Comment: @pratt as i can see above dataset is not empty as Size 2 is showing in log plus `Loc_details.get(0)` showing value So dataset is not null

Comment: data  is not empty please check log

Answer (score 0):

Hello could you try doing something like this, instead of creating a new adapter everytime try clearing the adapter and add the new list. This method should be in your adapter and mList should be the list that fills your adapter:

```
public void setAll(@NonNull
                   final List<Object> yourCustomObjectList) {
    mList.clear();
    mList.addAll(yourCustomObjectList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A7y6Mwik 
Please check log after implement your code

Answer (score 0):

You calling adapter first with no result then you fill form and expected that details fills into your RecyclerView and problem is that you getting result into fragment but your list don't have that result.

Now as per your code i tried and i hard coded return value of adapter's `getItemCount` into 1 and it was showing all method into logcat so i simply made your list static and now its work.

Please make your list static

```
static List<PPL_list_wrapper> Loc_details=new ArrayList<PPL_list_wrapper>();
```

Hope it help

As you saying your layout show both fragment at once. Its a issue of fragment add or replace so as per your code change this line

```
Add_PPL add_ppl=new Add_PPL();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,add_ppl);
```

Into this

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,add_ppl);
```

And for your second issue that the layout showing large margin please check your single row layout xml and make sure height is to `wrap_content` or post post your code here

Comment: Thankyou so much its working but there is few more issue i am facing 1) my fragment_2 change into fragment_1 but it messed up layout by showing both fragment at same time until i pressed add button again 2) my 1 recyclerview taking full screen and others start after after large margin between both of them

Comment: thankyou so much for your help i really appreciate it thanks alot